# DialogFragment vanishes on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

Although i saw many issues on this an tried to implement all of them i decided to ask this question again since none of the suggested methods worked for me.

Problem:
Im trying to show a custom dialog based on a DialogFragment inside an ActivityFragment.
the Activity is being recreated on orientation change since it has a different layout.
Every time that happens the DialogFragment vanishes. (i am using the latest support package)

Things i have tired:

1. using the onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance to try and save the dilaog.
2. Use setRetainInstance (true) in the dialog onCreate.
3. a static newInstance() method in the dialog.
4. override the dialog onDestroy to remove the destroy listener on the inner dialog

and some other documented solutions.
nothing seems to work, i tired with may variations of these solutions, the reason my custom dialog holds many ui elements in various states and i really have to get this to work.

If anyone could please provide some code to a solution it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
  Totem

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code yourself, and then we can help you debug it.

Comment: I would like to close my dialog on orientation change ON PURPOSE...  Could you provide some code to show how you did it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the FragmentManager is also retained through the onSaveInstanceState() of the parent which i neglected to call when overriding it in the ActivityFragment for my own purposes.

Thanks,
   Totem

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I do not understand how you fixed it. What did you neglect to call and where? onSaveInstanceState in the parent Activity?

Comment: @span - I believe he is saying he forgot to call super.onSaveInstanceState() in his child class.  The parent recreates the fragment in onSaveInstanceState, but can't if he doesn't call the super.